# How to prevent other event handlers, from first handler, in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling

If you attach two or more event handlers to an HTML element, they would be executed one after the other. However, if you want to stop the subsequent event handlers, based on a condition checked in the first handler, then what you should do?

For example:

```
<div id='target'>
</div>

<p id='result'>
</p>
```

I'd like to cancel the second handler, if the first handler is cancelled.

```
$(function() {
    var target = $('#target'),
        result = $('#result');
    target.click(function(e) {
        result.append('first handler<br />');
        // Here I want to cancel all subsequent event handlers
    });
    target.click(function(e) {
        result.append('second handler<br />');
    });
});
```

You can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/pFp7P/).

PS: I know that `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action of the HTML element (for example, preventing an HTTP GET request being sent because of the click on a link), and `e.preventPropagation()` causes the event from being propagated to its parent elements in the DOM tree. I also know that it's possible to use a middle variable, set it to true in first handler, and check it in subsequent handlers. But I want to see if there is a more neat, sophisticated solution to this problem or not.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

See `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` - http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

According to the jQuery API docs, this method:

> Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Comment: I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/pFp7P/2/) to reflect your answer. +1 and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is browser specific. See `dojo.stopEvent`:

```
dojo.stopEvent = function(/*Event*/ evt){
    // summary:
    //        prevents propagation and clobbers the default action of the
    //        passed event
    // evt: Event
    //        The event object. If omitted, window.event is used on IE.
    if(has("dom-addeventlistener") || (evt && evt.preventDefault)){
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
    }else{
        evt = evt || window.event;
        evt.cancelBubble = true;
        on._preventDefault.call(evt);
    }
};
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pFp7P/1/

Comment: This question relates to jQuery

Comment: This is a native solution; does it not work w/ jQuery anymore?