# How do I prevent a jQuery function from being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent other event handlers, from first handler, in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118489/how-to-prevent-other-event-handlers-from-first-handler-in-jquery)

I have two jQuery functions like this:

```
$('#click-me').live('click', function(event) {
    alert("Hello World");
    event.preventDefault();
});
$('#click-me').live('click', function(event) {
    alert("Goodbye World");
});
```

It may sound strange,  but let's say I don't want the second function (with the "goodbye world" alert to be executed),  how would I do that?  The event.preventDefault doesn't help.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Fyi, `.live()` is deprecated.

Comment: Only in up to date jQuery,  I am running an older app.

Comment: @FelixKling  Can you please stop commenting on everyones answers, when they actually work? And who cares if it is a duplicate,  there are hundreds of questions, I just didn't find any myself!

Comment: @Peter: I comment when I see fit. If the answers would work, I would not comment. I hope you realise that I did this to help you as well. And I care that it is a duplicate, because there is no need to duplicate information. Why have two (or more) questions about the same thing? It's important that the site does not get cluttered. Don't worry that you did not find it, that's why I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to prevent all following handlers from being triggered.

Comment: That worked acharm.  I will do mark this as answered when I can!  Thanks have have a good new year :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
var goodbyeCallback = function(event) {
   alert("Goodbye World");
}

$('#click-me').live('click', function(event) {
    alert("Hello World");
    $('#click-me').die('click', goodbyeCallback);
});
$('#click-me').live('click', goodbyeCallback);
```

There may be troubles with the order when the callbacks are fired; can't you join them to a single callback?

BTW: The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) says that `.live()` is deprecated.

Comment: Handlers are always fired in the order they are bound. So in this case, the first time the event is triggered, both handlers will be called. Also, `.live` and `.off` don't work together.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `live()` use `on()` and `off()`:

```
$('#click-me').on('click', canBeOnOrOff);

function canBeOnOrOff(event) {
  alert('goodbye world');

  // this removes the event handler from the click event
  $('#click-me').off('click', canBeOnOrOff);
}
```

Comment: This is not equivalent. OP uses event delegation, you are binding the handler directly to the element.

Comment: It is equivalent. .on() delegates events just like .live() did. In fact, .live() has been deprecated in favor of .on():

http://api.jquery.com/on/ (jump to "direct and delegated events")

Comment: Yes, I know you can use `.on` for that, but you are not doing so ;)