# Prevent event from triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I got two functions, one that collapses stuff when someone clicks the header of that collapsable, and I got a function that opens a modal, but the open modal icon that I use as a trigger to open the modal, is on the header of the collapsable, so when someone clicks the icon, it both opens the modal, and does the collapse stuff, but I just want to open the modal and not do the collapse stuff, so how can I prevent it from triggering my collapse?

**Collapse**

```
$(document).on('click', '.panel-heading', function () {

var valgtElement = $(this).next();

$.each($('.panel-collapse'), function (index, value) {

    if ($(this).attr('id') == valgtElement.attr('id')) {
        $(this).collapse('toggle');
    } else {
        if ($(this).hasClass('in')) {
            $(this).collapse('toggle');
        }

    }

});

});
```

**Icon click**

```
$('body').on('click', '.fa-trash-o', function () {

$('#slettModal').modal();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$('body').on('click', '.fa-trash-o', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#slettModal').modal();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just use event.stopPropagation()

[Link](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) for more details

```
$('body').on('click', '.fa-trash-o', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
 $('#slettModal').modal();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('body').on('click', '.fa-trash-o',
             function (event) {
                event.stopImmediatePropagation()
                $('#slettModal').modal();

  });
```

make sure to include the `event` parameter in the function declaration

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

[How to prevent other event handlers, from first handler, in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118489/how-to-prevent-other-event-handlers-from-first-handler-in-jquery)